# Реализация собственного класса Matrix

Tags: c++

Создаю свой класс Matrix(использовать контейнеры STL нельзя, все ресурсы управляются вручную). Начал реализовать конструктор и оператор перемещения, но начинают появляться сомнения, что ушел в какую то не ту сторону. Можно узнать как можно сделать данные конструкторы и операторы наиболее эффективными с точки зрения памяти и времени выполнения?

Сам класс Matrix:

```
template <typename T>
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        T *data = nullptr;
        size_t rows; 
        size_t cols;
```

Конструктор и оператор:

```
Matrix(Matrix &&other) noexcept : rows((other.rows)), cols((other.cols)), data(other.data)
        {
            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;
        }

        Matrix &operator=(Matrix<T> &&other) noexcept
        {

            if (&other == this)
            {
                return *this;
            }

            if (rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
            {
                std::cout << "Ошибка присваивания матриц разного размеры" << std::endl;
                exit(-1);
            }

            clean();

            std::swap(data, other.data);
            std::swap(rows, other.rows);
            std::swap(cols, other.cols);

            other.data = nullptr;
            other.rows = 0;
            other.cols = 0;

            return *this;
        }
```

Функция очистки:

```
void clean()
{
    if (nullptr != data)
    {
        rows = 0;
        cols = 0;
        delete[] data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Премещающий конструктор сделан нормально, но непонятно зачем там двойные скобки.

Еще есть более выпендрежный способ записать то же самое: `: rows(std::exchange(other.rows, 0))`. Тогда отдельное зануление в теле конструктора не нужно.

---

В перемещающем присваивании проверка на совпадение размеров смотрится очень странно, я бы убрал. `swap` тоже смотрится странно; раз вы все равно зануляете поле, можно обойтись `rows = other.rows; other.rows = 0;`.

Есть трюк, позволяющий в 99% случаев писать присваивание не думая, называется [copy & swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/2752075). Пишется так:

```
Matrix &operator=(Matrix<T> other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(data, other.data);
    std::swap(rows, other.rows);
    std::swap(cols, other.cols);
    return *this;
}
```

Прелесть в том, то он может одновременно работать как копирующий (если есть копирующий конструктор) и как перемещающий (если есть перемещающий конструктор). При такой записи проверка на самоприсваивание больше не нужна, и бросок исключения из копирующего/перемещающего конструктора не оставляет класс в неправильном состоянии.

---

В `clear()` забыли занулить указатель.

---

В низкоуровневых классах а-ля "матрица" не стоит печатать ничего в консоль и/или закрывать программу. Об ошибке лучше сообщать броском исключения, или возвращаемым значением функции (для `operator=` последнее не подойдет), или чем-то таким.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо! По поводу проверки на совпадения размеров. Сделал для того, чтобы не смогли присваивать матрицы разных размеров(например матрице 2х2 присвоить матрицу 10х10).
И броса исключение вы имели ввиду так: std::exception("Ошибка присваивания матриц разного размеры")?

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко *"Сделал для того, чтобы"* Ну это понятно, вы просто словами повторили то что у вас в коде написано. :) А я вам говорю, что это плохая идея. Вы сами потом взвоете от этой проверки. Например, если попробовать сделать `std::vector` матриц разного размера, а потом отсортировать их `std::sort` по какому-то признаку - сработает ваша проверка.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко У `std::exception` нет конструктора, принимающего строку. Его сделали только в MSVC, но это нестандартная фигня. Лучше взять его наследника `std::runtime_error`, у которого этот конструктор есть. Еще `throw` перед ним забыли.